# How to remap the ^ symbol

Tags: autohotkey

On a danish-layout keyboard I have to press twice on the "^" symbol in order to get out one "^" symbol. I would like to remap this symbol so that I only have to press it once.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SC029::Send {Text}^
```

or

```
SC029::Send {Blind}{Text}^
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text

`029` is the [scan code](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) of this key

Comment: Then  the scan code is different on your system. Try to find out the right one using [this method](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: Scan codes are different per keyboard specification